# Is there any authentication scheme relying only on the "secret" question?

Tags: authentication

I know it's standard for websites to use usernames and passwords to authenticate users. From what I've read, question based authentication is usually used to either reset a password, or employ two-factor authentication, but I'm wondering if anybody has used or seen a strictly question based Single Factor Authentication method, and if so, what type of resources was it being used to protect?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen loads of single factor authentication methods, all the usual ones, digital badges, physical tokens, bio metrics etc.

As for a Q and A type challenge/repose thing, I have only ever seen them when recovering forgotten passwords.

When you think about it they are not much difference from username/password. Both have a public part, the question/username and both have a secret part the answer/password.

If I was forced to use a single factor authentication method the challenge/response method would be at the bottom of my list, as the secret part would be far to predictable and guessable.

Comment: Heck, when I'm asked to supply an answer to a "personal question" I still generate a long, complex string like my password.

Comment: @schroeder I do the same thing. It is however a little odd trying to tell a customer service employee over the phone that yes, the name of your first pet really was ":.RSBw8D9'7,)z?.$goGl]x]ci;M-i'<rj:eCk7"